# cortex-m: where is exception number of interrupted interrupt stored

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling, cortex-m

For NVIC to be able to compare priorities it needs to know them.

That seems simple at first (it can get them from exception number; exception number of current interrupt is in `SCB->ICSR bits [5:0]`) but what happens when interrupt is interrupted? Where is exception number (or priority) of interrupted interrupt stored?

I've checked Yiu's book but can't find the answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Interrupt Program Status register contains "contains the exception type number of the current Interrupt Service Routine (ISR)" according to the ARM documentation.

Comment: Seem like i missed that IPSR is part of PSR. So it is pushed and then restored from stack (so exception number can be restored). Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

NVIC_IPRn(Interrupt Priority Register) stores interrupt priorities as per bit description.
It's address starts from 0xE000E400 + 4n (secure)

Following is the bit assignment of NVIC_IPRn(0..128) register as per arm arm.
[image: NVIC_IPRn bit assignment]

eg., LSB of NVIC_IPR0 contains the priority of INTR0.